# checking null value in database through sqlquery C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have entered a user's name that exists in the DB. The name has only first and last name. so the middle name is empty and it is stored in the DB as `null`. To get the employee id of the user, i have used the following query. but the value of obj after executing the query is `null`. The first and last names are stored in an array. I have checked their values. Their values are ok.

Can you please tell me why the object is not fetching nay value.

```
SqlCommand cmm1= new SqlCommand ();
cmm1.CommandText = ("Select empID from empPersonalInfo where empFirstName= '" + arr[0].ToString() + "' and empMiddleName= '" + System.DBNull.Value + "' and empLastName= '" + arr[2].ToString() + "' ");            
cmm1.Connection = conn;
obj = cmm1.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compare NULL using equals '=', use 'IS NULL' instead:

```
cmm1.CommandText = ("Select empID from empPersonalInfo where empFirstName= '" + 
              arr[0].ToString() + "' and empMiddleName IS NULL and empLastName= '" + 
              arr[2].ToString() + "' ");
```

BTW, that query really doesn't make a lot of sense.  Perhaps :

```
empMiddleName IS NULL OR empMiddleName =  @somevalue
```

**Plus, please note**: you are  possibly open to SQL Injection attacks. Use parameters rather than concatenating user input values.

Answer (score 2):

For comparing a field against `null` use `empMiddleName IS NULL`

*You should use [Parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) to prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).*

Answer (score 1):

empMiddleName= '" + System.DBNull.Value + "' is incorrect. There is no = operator for NULL value.

Change it to empMiddleName is null .

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLParameter object for passing parameters to the query as below:

```
SqlCommand command = 
        new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = @Username", conn);

    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Username", "Justin Niessner"));
    obj = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to check that middle name should be equal null or middle name should be equal to value you have passed in query.
```

I hope blow query query can full fill your requirement.

```
cmm1.CommandText = ("Select empID from empPersonalInfo where empFirstName= '" + 
                  arr[0].ToString() + "' and ((empMiddleName IS NULL) or(empMiddleName='"+arr[1].ToString()+"')) and empLastName= '" + 
                  arr[2].ToString() + "' ");
```